# Eliminar cero de string

Tags: java

Supongamos tengo lo siguiente

```
String cadena = "00015502"
```

Necesito elimianr solo los primeros ceros, un replace o replaceall no me valdria porque sino tambien reemplazaria el cero que esta entre el 5 y el 2

He probado esta solución pero con este valor no me vale : 001000

```
cadena.replace("0"," ").trim().replace(" ","0");
```

Tb he probado esto pero no me compila

```
cadena.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

Estoy usando java

Comment: ¿Siempre habrá tres ceros al principio? O, ¿Puede haber más? ¿Puede haber menos? Ejemplo: 00000156 ó 01234567

Comment: puede existir más

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma mas simple en estos casos es utilizar una expresión regex:

```
public class Remover {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-ReplaceAll");
        System.out.println(removerCeros("00015502"));
        System.out.println(removerCeros("100015502"));
        
        System.out.println("-Replace");
        System.out.println(removerCerosReplace("00015502"));
        System.out.println(removerCerosReplace("^0+100015502"));
    }

    public static String removerCeros(String cadena) {
        cadena = cadena.replaceAll("^0+", "")      ;

        return cadena;
    }

    public static String removerCerosReplace(String cadena) {
        cadena = cadena.replace("^0+", "")      ;

        return cadena;
    }
}

// Salida de datos:
-ReplaceAll
15502
100015502

-Replace
00015502
100015502
```

La expresión regular indica:
`^` que la cadena inicie con `0` y `+` seleccione todos los ceros siguientes.

Según tu error es raro, porque tanto `replaceAll` como `replaceFirst` deberian de funcionar igual con esta expresión regular, lo que debes de tener en cuenta es que el método `replace` funciona diferente, `replace` busca el texto tal cual se lo indicas  si le pasamos `^0+` entenderá que dentro del texto debe buscar esa secuencia de 3 caracteres y los remplazara, mientras que `replaceAll` y `replaceFirst` entenderán que lo que le pasas es una expresión regular que les dice que remplacen todos los ceros iniciales de una cadena.

Comment: Justo he editado mi pregunta con una solucion parecida pero no me compila

Comment: tuve que cambiarlo asi y me funciona: replaceAll( "^0+(?!\$)", "")

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera de hacerlo también, es usando un ciclo `for`:

```
static String cadena_nueva = "";
static Boolean bandera = false;

public static String remover(String numero){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numero.length(); i++){
        
        if(numero.charAt(i) != '0'){
            bandera = true;
        }
        
        if(bandera){
            cadena_nueva += numero.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    
    return cadena_nueva;
}
```

Se manda llamar el `método` junto con el parámetro y te devuelve la cadena sin los `0` del principio:

```
System.out.println(remover("0006540053"));
```

Salida:

> 6540053